# USACO Ski Course Design

Tags: recursion

So I was doing this problem, but it led me to a different solution. The actual solution is this:

Problem -
Farmer John has N hills on his farm (1 <= N <= 1,000), each with an integer elevation in the range 0 .. 100. In the winter, since there is abundant snow on these hills, FJ routinely operates a ski training camp.

Unfortunately, FJ has just found out about a new tax that will be assessed next year on farms used as ski training camps. Upon careful reading of the law, however, he discovers that the official definition of a ski camp requires the difference between the highest and lowest hill on his property to be strictly larger than 17. Therefore, if he shortens his tallest hills and adds mass to increase the height of his shorter hills, FJ can avoid paying the tax as long as the new difference between the highest and lowest hill is at most 17.

If it costs x^2 units of money to change the height of a hill by x units, what is the minimum amount of money FJ will need to pay? FJ can change the height of a hill only once, so the total cost for each hill is the square of the difference between its original and final height. FJ is only willing to change the height of each hill by an integer amount.

Solution -
The problem can be solved with different approaches. A simple idea is of course brute-force -- try all possible elevations and find the minimum amount. We can try all possible values as follows: try the modification for elevation interval (0,17) then (1,18), (2,19), ..., (83,100). For each elevation interval (i,i+17), we need to calculate the cost for each hill j:

If the elevation of hill j, say hill[j], is in the interval (i,i+17) then there is no cost.
If it is less than i then the cost increases by (i-hill[j])^2
If it is greater than i+17 then the cost increases by (hill[j]-(i+17))^2
Is there any better way of doing this i mean if limits exceed drastically

```
import sys

def main():
    hill_heights = []
    for _ in range(int(sys.stdin.readline().strip("\n"))):
        hill_heights.append(int(sys.stdin.readline().strip("\n")))
    hill_heights = sorted(hill_heights)
    print(hill_heights)

    print(make_less(hill_heights=hill_heights, sum=0))

def make_less(hill_heights, sum):
    if hill_heights[-1] - hill_heights[0] <= 17:
        return sum
    else:
        difference = hill_heights[-1] - hill_heights[0] - 17
        hill_heights[0] = hill_heights[0] + difference//2
        sum += (difference//2)**2
        difference = difference - difference//2
        hill_heights[-1] = hill_heights[-1] - difference
        sum += difference**2
        difference = difference - difference
        print(hill_heights)
        return make_less(sorted(hill_heights), sum)
    
main()
```

But this comes with the wrong answer. However, the resulting list does satisfy all the conditions. Do you guys know where I may be going wrong?

The resulting list is - [43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 46, 46, 46, 48, 50, 52, 53, 55, 55, 56, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60]

Input - 2nd Input on USACO website

Output - 22888

Expected Output - 22946

Comment: Please [edit] your post to credit the original source of this problem.  See our requirements on referencing material written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: We discourage "is my answer correct?" or "please troubleshoot my solution" questions, as they are unlikely to be of use to others in the future.  Our mission is to build up an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, in the form of questions and answers.  Also, we're not a coding site, and questions about your code are off-topic here.  Please replace your code with concise pseudocode.